# How to create Office documents on a Linux based server?

Tags: c#, linux, reporting, interopservices

I developed a "Reporting App" on C# that creates reports (basically on .doc's and .ppt's formats (using the MS Office interops libraries)) based on some parameters received from the user. Everything works as expected when the app is executed on a Windows Server or computer. The problem is that one costumer's server is Linux based. Is it possible to create Office documents on a Linux environment? Any ideas how?

I am currently using these libraries:

```
Microsoft.Office.Core
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint
```

Please help.

Comment: Office Interop has a hard dependency on MS Office being present, and COM. These aren't available in Linux, at least without WINE but good luck getting that all working. Instead you should use libraries that don't rely on external assemblies to generate these documents, such as Open XML SDK, EPPlus, NPOI, ClosedXML, DocX etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for cross platform or cases when Office is not installed on the hosting machine

Comment: this is probably a better and more portable approach, but means re-writing everything.